# Which service returned by Context.getSystemService will never be null?

Tags: android

The documentation for [Context.getSystemService](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getSystemService%28java.lang.String%29) states

> Returns: The service or null if the name does not exist.

The list of accepted names is listed as

```
 ACTIVITY_SERVICE
 ALARM_SERVICE
 AUDIO_SERVICE
 BATTERY_SERVICE
 CARRIER_CONFIG_SERVICE
 CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE
 DOWNLOAD_SERVICE
 INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE
 JOB_SCHEDULER_SERVICE
 KEYGUARD_SERVICE
 LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE
 LOCATION_SERVICE
 MEDIA_ROUTER_SERVICE
 NETWORK_STATS_SERVICE
 NOTIFICATION_SERVICE
 POWER_SERVICE
 SEARCH_SERVICE
 SENSOR_SERVICE
 STORAGE_SERVICE
 TELEPHONY_SERVICE
 TELEPHONY_SUBSCRIPTION_SERVICE
 UI_MODE_SERVICE
 VIBRATOR_SERVICE
 WIFI_SERVICE
 WINDOW_SERVICE
```

Assuming I pass one of those names to `getSystemService`at some point after the start of `onCreate` in an Activity or Service, will the return value ever be null?

If so, are there any of the accepted names that will always return a non-null value, or do I need to null check the return values of all calls to `getSystemService`?

Comment: It might return `null` if the system service does not exist on that device, due to API level. For example, `JOB_SCHEDULER_SERVICE` would only exist on API Level 21+. Older devices might return `null` if you request that system service. I usually do an API level check before calling `getSystemService()`, so I have not tried this personally.

Comment: That's a good point. If I'm on the correct API, can I assume the return value will be non-null?

Comment: I have never checked for `null` and have never run into a problem. That being said, I cannot promise you anything. :-)

Answer (score 7):

Instant apps, for which `PackageManager.isInstantApp()` returns `true`, don't have access to the following system services:

`DEVICE_POLICY_SERVICE,
FINGERPRINT_SERVICE, 
SHORTCUT_SERVICE, 
USB_SERVICE,
WALLPAPER_SERVICE, 
WIFI_P2P_SERVICE}, 
WIFI_SERVICE,
WIFI_AWARE_SERVICE.`

For these services this method will return `null`.
Generally, if you are running as an instant app you should always check whether the result of this method is null.

And since the `getSystemService()` method is annotated as `@Nullable`, as a rule of thumb I would always check for `null` :).